# Processing unpartitioned data with AWS Glue using bookmarking

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have data being written from Kafka to a directory in s3 with a structure like this:

```
s3://bucket/topics/topic1/files1...N
s3://bucket/topics/topic2/files1...N
.
.
s3://bucket/topics/topicN/files1...N
```

There is already a lot of data in this bucket and I want to use AWS Glue to transform it into parquet and partition it, but there is way too much data to do it all at once. I was looking into bookmarking and it seems like you can't use it to only read the most recent data or to process data in chunks. Is there a recommended way of processing data like this so that bookmarking will work for when new data comes in?

Also, does bookmarking require that spark or glue has to scan my entire dataset each time I run a job to figure out which files are greater than the last runs max_last_modified timestamp? That seems pretty inefficient especially as the data in the source bucket continues to grow.

Comment: Is your data partitioned by topics? If yes then you can process your data partition by partition.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned that Glue wants all similar files (files with same structure and purpose) to be under one folder, with optional subfolders.

```
s3://my-bucket/report-type-a/yyyy/mm/dd/file1.txt
s3://my-bucket/report-type-a/yyyy/mm/dd/file2.txt
...
s3://my-bucket/report-type-b/yyyy/mm/dd/file23.txt
```

All of the files under report-type-a folder must be of the same format.  Put a different report like report-type-b in a different folder.

You might try putting just a few of your input files in the proper place, running your ETL job, placing more files in the bucket, running again, etc.

I tried this by getting the current files working (one file per day), then back-filling historical files.  Note however, that this did not work completely.  I have been getting files processed ok in `s3://my-bucket/report-type/2019/07/report_20190722.gzp`, but when I tried to add past files to 's3://my-bucket/report-type/2019/05/report_20190510.gzip`, Glue did not "see" or process the file in the older folder.

However, if I moved the old report to the current partition, it worked: `s3://my-bucket/report-type/2019/07/report_20190510.gzip` .

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue bookmarking works only with a select few formats (more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html)) and when read using `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options` function. Along with this `job.init()` and `job.commit()` should also be present in the glue script. You can checkout a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65502221/glue-bookmark-is-not-working-when-reading-s3-files-via-spark-dataframe).