# Glue bookmark is not working when reading S3 files via spark dataframe

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a S3 buckets storing .gz files (json format). There will be more files sending to this bucket hourly. I want to use Glue to read from the S3 bucket incrementally (daily), convert the .gz to parquet and write back to another S3 bucket.

I figured that I can use Glue bookmark to do the incremental files reading/converting/writing. However, I found if I read the .gz files in spark dataframe, the bookmark is not working. In another word, my below glue job won't read the files incrementally. It reads all the files from that bucket. I did enable Bookmark in that Glue job.

Did I miss anything here? Do I need to read the files via glue dynamic dataframe rather than spark data frame?

I actually don't know how to read the .gz files via glue dynamic dataframe properly. Based on what I understand, to use Glue dynamic dataframe, I need to create a Glue crawler against that bucket to create a table. However, there are a lot of folders inside that bucket with each date name as folder name. When I tried to create crawler on that bucket, it created a whole bunch of tables in Glue...

Please, any suggestions or advices would be appreciated!

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, TimestampType, LongType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,year,month,dayofmonth,to_date,from_unixtime


## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

srcDf = spark.read.json("s3://source/*/*")

partitionDf = srcDf.withColumn("date_col", to_date(col("timestamp"), 'yyyy-MM-dd')).withColumn("year", year(col("date_col"))).withColumn("month", month(col("date_col"))).withColumn("day", dayofmonth(col("date_col"))).repartition(1)

dynamicdf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(partitionDf, glueContext, "test_nest")

apilogs = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dynamicdf, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://destination/", "partitionKeys": ["year", "month", "day"]}, format = "glueparquet", transformation_ctx = "apilogs")


job.commit()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Bookmarks are a glue specific feature and do not work with spark data frames. You will need to read as a dynamic frame in order for you to track the previously processed files. Its important to have `job.init()`, `transformation_ctx` and the `job.commit()`.  The above is documented in a bit more detail [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html).

In order to read gzipped json files, you could use the following:

```
dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
                connection_type = "s3",
                connection_options = {"paths": [your_s3_bucket], 'compression': 'gzip' },
                format = "json", transformation_ctx = "dyf"))
```

Comment: Thanks Eman, I gave it a try and seems like the dynamic frame read nothing from my .gz files. `dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type ="s3",connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://test/*/*"], "compression": "gzip"  },format = "json", transformation_ctx ="dyf")`

Comment: Instead of using * can you try using the recurse option as follows: `dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type ="s3",connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://test/"], "compression": "gzip", "recurse": True },format = "json", transformation_ctx ="dyf")`